# API Mercadolibre - Atributos

Tags: c#, api, rest, mercadolibre

Los molesto con lo siguiente:
Estoy implementando una integración con el api de MercadoLibre y necesito enviarle al Item atributos que posiblemente no estén dentro de los que me da la categoría para usar.

Por ejemplo: si la categoría me da para usar COLOR o TALLE, y necesito PESO, se me complica, puedo pasarle los valores de PESO en COLOR pero no sería lo indicado.
Si le intento pasar un atributo que no corresponda da error.

¿Alguien se ha encontrado con lo mismo y pudo solucionarlo?
Quedo atento a cualquier pregunta por si no me expliqué bien.

Gracias!

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Un ejemplo del código que has intentado usar y lo que ha fallado (todo como texto, en lo posible) le vendría bien a tu pregunta. Recuerda que puedes editarla todas las veces que haga falta, usando el enlace Editar que está justo bajo las etiquetas.